# Open link in a different panel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a page that dynamically generated a list of links to a web page (aspx) that opens an image.  I do not have direct access to the PDF, only through the ASPX. The code behind is C#.

So if I have a page that has codes that looks like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlImageList" runat="server" Visible="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <a href="http://someserver.com/EDocs/View.aspx?application=MB&amp;seqnum=260">
    View Scan # 1</a>
   </asp:Panel>
  </td>
  <td>Open Image here</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How do I open the view.aspx link in the cell labels 'Open Image Here'??

AHIA, 
LarryR...

Comment: By "image" you actually mean "pdf" correct?  Also, it's not clear what you are asking.  Are you trying to put the pdf inline in the table without having them click the link or do you have some app that reads the table and needs to download the link?  This is a little confusing

Comment: Sorry Chris... I'm looking for the user to be able to click on a link & have the link opened in the cell there 'Open Image Here' is in the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an embedded iframe as shown here:

http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php

This is essentially doing what you want -- clicking a link (click on any of the "HTML" or "PDF" links) brings up a file in the embedded iframe.